# making conditional inside mysql query

Tags: mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
'SELECT conversation_id, viewed_on,('max_unixtime().' - last_reply) AS newest_conversation FROM `Conversation_Participant` WHERE `user_id`='.$self->{user}->get('id').' ORDER BY newest_conversation DESC'
```

I need to set newest_conversation only when max_unixtime() - last_reply > last_viewed..

how can i set the if statement within my query?

Comment: And when `max_unixtime() - last_reply **IS NOT** > last_viewed`, then what should happen?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [CASE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html).

```
...CASE WHEN max_unixtime() - last_reply > last_viewed 
        THEN ('max_unixtime().' - last_reply) 
        ELSE NULL END AS newest_conversation...
```